# HAProxy check backend on 2 ports

Tags: apache, tomcat, haproxy, ports

we have apache in front of tomcat. it happens that the tomcat crashes and the apache still serve the webpage with a 503 page.
there's a way, via HAProxy to check both ports: 80 and 8080 and then bring the node up?
I added the `http-check expect rstatus (2|3)[0-9][0-9]` and the `http-check expect ! rstatus ^5` but none of the 2 detected that tomcat was unreachable while the apache was providing the service.

thank you a lot
Nick

Answer (score 0):

If your health check is configured correctly, you don't have to test both ports -- just configure the health check to send a request to apache that will be served by tomcat, using [`option httpchk`](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.6.html#4-option%20httpchk).  A 503 response will cause cause that server to be declared unhealthy.

Comment: I update the question because I already did the httpchk and the http-check

Comment: `curl -v http://apache:80/resource-from-tomcat` and verify the response code.  You really shouldn't need `http-check expect` anything but you do need something like `option httpchk GET /the/page/from/tomcat HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:\ hostname-apache-expects-to-see` to specify which resource you want to test.  If you already have that, please show it.

Comment: I've in the backend the `option httpchk GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:\ www.mysite.com`

Comment: DOES `GET /` return an error when tomcat isn't working?  If not, you'll want to health check against a page that does.

Comment: I modified the page that doesn't have a redirect and worked correctly!

Answer (score 0):

the problem was the / at the end that did a redirect. once modified, works correctly with the expect 200.